# Unable to select a div with class

Tags: jquery, html, ios, swift, uiwebview

In my iOS app, I am opening an URL in `UIWebView`. I want to hide the `div` with `class="main-container scrollable"`. I am not expert in `jQuery`. The source of the page has,

```
<head></head>
<body class="scope" controller="MainCtrl"
    <div class="scope toast-top-right" id="toast-container"></div>
    <div class="app-container">
        <div id="left-panel" class="slide-panel” ui-view="leftPanel"></div>
        <div id="main-panel" class="partial-container">
            <div class="scope" ui-view="navbar"></div>
            <div class="scope" ui-view="mainPanel">
                <div class="page-home scope">
                    <div class="main-container scrollable"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried,

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("$('.main-container.scrollable').hide()")
```

also tried,

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("alert($('.partial-container').children().eq(1).find('.main-container').length)")
```

It returns `"0"`.

How could I select the `div` with `class`, `"main-container"`?

Comment: The alert show 1 for length, http://jsfiddle.net/oaL1nsa3/

Comment: The second line returns `0` because you are selecting the first child of _.partial-container_ (which is div with class scope) and then grabbing the length of its children (_which doesn't have any_) where the class of the child is _.main-container_.

Comment: Check what the response of this is:  `webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("alert($('.main-container.scrollable').length);")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that using `$('#main-panel').find('.main-container')`

Answer (score 1):

You code seems fine. It will select the div you want to select using jQuery. Problem could be that you are trying to access DOM when the element has not been created in Webview, hence it is returning 0 or not selecting the element. Try executing the code to hide after the page has fully loaded.

I am not an expert in UIWebView, but may be you can try to execute this code on some tap event or - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView.